# How do i add a Blob Storage Binding?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

So i am working on azure function my goal is to have an azure function that is triggerd by an http request that have a blob storage binding which i can retrive files through but when i try to add my blob in binding the function stop working even though i didnt even add any code the main function

this is the binding setting i am using

```
{
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "inputblob",
      "path": "test/{name}",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnection"
    }
```

this is the main function i have right now

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(f"HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.")
```

but it is not working it give me a 500 error when trying to trigger the function

Answer (score 0):

So, in your bindings you specify a  blob trigger, but your code is expecting an http trigger. That is not going to work.

The code for a blob trigger takes an `InputStream` represeting the blob:

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info('Python Blob trigger function processed %s', myblob.name)
```

Also, the binding should like this (note: the type is `blobTrigger`, not `blob`):

```json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "name": "myblob",
            "type": "blobTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
            "connection":"MyStorageAccountAppSetting"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is also very well explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example)

Comment: thank you for your reply may i ask how would this work if i need the trigger to be an HTTP request

Note:I tried using the following code and still gave me an error

Comment: @BilalEdelbi well, you cannot combine an http trigger with a blob trigger so can you tell me more about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @BilalEdelbi Also, please post the whole error message. Otherwise it is hard to tell what the exact problem is.

Comment: my error message is a simple 500 web error which I found it out it means that it didn't find any better error message to give me

what I am trying to accomplish basically is

that I have 5 excel files that I need to transform using pandas so I did the transformation locally 
but my goal is to make it so they are uploaded to azure blob storage though another process other people are developing and when i send the http request i want the function to be able to take the files from blob storage and process them in azure function and in the end put the output in another blob somewhere

Comment: You should check the logs, there must be more information there!